# How can I get the attributeSet of product with his id with GraphQL?

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, graphql

I was using GraphQL to get the products of my shop and I can´t get his attributes. In my shop, there is several products with is unique attributeSet. I use the next query to get the attribute_set_id of the product:

```
query{
  products(filter: {category_id: {eq: "1"}}){
    items{
      attribute_set_id
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the attributeSet of this product with the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like attribute set is a metadata that is not available in graphql definition.

my explanation would be that PWA Magento frontend does not need this data to surface and therefore no graphql query was written to retrieve the data you're seeking.

Of course, you can create a custom graphql entry point that will have its own resolver. The graphql architecture being up and running already, it is fast to add your own entry point

Comment: my answer is about attribute set, not attributes